# How to install wildcard architecture packages on Ubuntu. Trying to add gives dpkg: error: architecture 'any', "all" is reserved and cannot be added

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I expect to install packages created for different architecture onto my ubuntu server - and since those packages being architecture agnostic - they use a wild card

I want to add the wild-card such as "any" or "all" as a foreign architecture

I referred to https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO.
Since

But When I try to run command

```
enter code here
dpkg --add-architecture all
dpkg: error: architecture 'all' is reserved and 
cannot be added
root@arm-t2-imgtest-1-base-os-1:/opt/ucaastage# 
dpkg: error: architecture 'any' is reserved and 
cannot be addeddpkg: error: architecture 'any' is 
reserved and cannot be added
```

Based on below comment by @guiverc I referred to  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchHowto

As suggested in that I made an entry in /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
as follows.. but after that when I run "pkg --print-foreign-architectures" gives an error "nknown
option 'foreign-architecture'"

```
# cat /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
  foreign-architecture all

dpkg --print-foreign-architectures        dpkg: 
error: configuration error: 
/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown 
option 'foreign-architecture'

apt update
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchHowto ??   Multiarch is not enabled on Ubuntu by default for the reason specified ; you used the Debian notes as you're using Debian?? or Ubuntu Server you mention??  Why not look up Ubuntu docs?

Comment: Hello guiverc . Thanks - after your directed me I read teh wiki and as per that I made an entry in /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch .. as directed but that gives an error - I am including that in edited question

Answer (score 1):

Since I did not find a direct answer to my question

Intially I though I needed to do something for "adding" the architecture "all" .so I install install time I added a  suffix :all to package name and was happy that it installs well

```
apt install <my packagename>:all
```

And even more interesting - when using "all" wildcards - it is NOT necessary to specify the architecture suffix - so

```
apt install <my packagename>
```

works just fine as far as you have a repository defined and have the packages with architecture="all" present